# Download OpenStreetMap data -> connection refused

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, plugins, download

When I try to download an `OSM` by means of the QGIS `OpenStreetMap` plug-in I always get:

```
Download failed. Connection refused.
```

When I try the same with the OSM downloader plug-in I get at least an error code:`10061`.

It doesn't matter if I select canvas, layer or manual, the result is always the same.

running QGIS 2.16.1, Windows 10 64bit

Comment: What is the plugin's exact name? Is it "OSMDownloader"?

Comment: yes, the second one, https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMDownloader/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OSM platform status page shows there are currently some major issues with reaching the Overpass API servers, which support the download options, with at least the Overpass Turbo server experiencing a DOS (Denial Of Service) attack. I also had issues downloading data yesterday, so this seems to be an ongoing issue for now:

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Platform_Status

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you requested an area too large for API download.

Try again with a smaller area, or download pbf extracts from Geofabrik.

Otherwise, make sure you are not blocked by your firewall or proxy.

Comment: I tried it with a very small area but as described. I don't use a proxy, only a personal firewall but that is properly configured.